# Rails server not working showing "TCPServer Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My server was working fine until this happened. Please help me out on this.
I don't know why this error is coming.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-05-25 16:36:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-05-25 16:36:06] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-05-25 16:36:06] WARN  TCPServer Error: Only one usage of each socket     address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2)
Uncaught exception: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network  address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:132:in `listen'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:113:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
C:/NEW/newcharityapp5/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/NEW/newcharityapp5/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: This exception looks like something related to networking and operation, not to the programming of your specific rails application, so [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) is probably a better place than StackOverflow to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running WEBrick on other port

Try this in your terminal

```
rails server -p 3001
```

This will help